# Android button looks different after rotating to landscape and still after rotating back

Tags: android, shapes, material-design, layer-list, floating-action-button

I created my button following [this](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/03/how-to-make-floating-action-button-fab.html?m=1) tutorial. It looks pretty good.

But if I rotate my device screen to landscape, the button looks different.
Do you have some idea, why this is happening?
If you need some code, please let me know!

Button as it should:

[image: Button as it should]

Button as it after rotating:

[image: Button as it after rotating]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you to use FloatingActionButton included in [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

Simply add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'` to your Gradle file, and use the [FloatingActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) view class into your layout!

Example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable" />
```

Comment: There are known issues with the FloatingActionButton and I suggest not using it just yet for release versions. FAB doesn't have elevation or margin on devices running Lollipop.